# Android collapsing Action bar with swipeable tabs

Tags: android, android-studio, android-actionbar, android-viewpager, android-tabs

I'm trying to achieve a page as shown in the [link](https://camo.githubusercontent.com/97497a24719b85f5d618cba66ac4d23ccfdd7023/687474703a2f2f692e696d6775722e636f6d2f615069333243712e676966). Can anyone please help me how to get it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

https://github.com/kaedea/Andriod-Seamless-ViewPager-Header

I Referred This example its working fine for me.please try this one surely  u ll got.

Answer (score 1):

Try this library ,Seamless viewpager 
https://github.com/kaedea/Andriod-Seamless-ViewPager-Header

Answer (score 0):

For expanding and collapsing toolbars (doesn't matter if it has tabs or not):

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/main_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

      <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Comment: i guess without using collapsing toolbar it cannot expand and hide toolbar

Comment: Can you use ActionBars instead of ToolBars for the collapsing effects? Trying to get away from AppbarLayout because of theme issues.

Answer (score 0):

Try this XML: and in view pager you can get swipes as per tab of tablayout selection.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        android:id="@+id/main_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
            android:id="@+id/fab_addProfile"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom|right"
            android:layout_margin="@dimen/_5sdp"
            app:backgroundTint="@color/colorPrimary"
            app:elevation="@dimen/_2sdp"
            app:fabSize="normal"
            android:visibility="gone"
            app:rippleColor="@color/textPrimary"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_vector_plus_white"
            app:useCompatPadding="true" />

        <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
            android:id="@+id/appbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

            <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
                android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
                app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|snap"
                app:titleEnabled="false">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    app:layout_collapseMode="parallax">

                    <FrameLayout
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                        <ImageView
                            android:id="@+id/dv_coverImage"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="@dimen/_100sdp"
                            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                            android:alpha="0.85"
                            android:tint="@color/black_translucent"
                            android:src="@drawable/bg_profile" />

                        <FrameLayout
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_50sdp"
                            android:weightSum="1">

                            <ImageView
                                android:id="@+id/dv_profile_pic"
                                android:layout_width="@dimen/_80sdp"
                                android:layout_height="@dimen/_80sdp"
                                android:layout_margin="@dimen/_10sdp" />

                        </FrameLayout>
                    </FrameLayout>
                </LinearLayout>

                <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                    app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"
                    app:navigationIcon="@drawable/ic_menu_white"
                    app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />

            </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
                    android:id="@+id/tabLayout"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
                    android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackground"
                    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
                    app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
                    app:tabGravity="fill"
                    app:tabIndicatorColor="@color/white"
                    app:tabMode="fixed"
                    app:tabSelectedTextColor="@color/white"
                    app:tabTextAppearance="@style/AppTheme.ProfileTab"
                    app:tabTextColor="@color/darkGreen" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

        <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
            android:id="@+id/nestedScrollView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="fill_vertical"
            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

            <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
                android:id="@+id/viewpager"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent" />
        </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
    </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>

    <include layout="@layout/view_progress_view" />
</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: can you please tell in detail about "view_progress_view" ?

Comment: That's a progressview i created for my personal use, you can ignore that. Removing that line won't affect other code

Answer (score -1):

```
Try this one

<android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/swipeContainer"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/tabanim_maincontent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/white">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/tabanim_appbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">


        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways|enterAlwaysCollapsed">

            <!-- View that will be hidden when video goes fullscreen -->
            <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/nonVideoLayout"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@color/white">

                // your view

            </RelativeLayout>


        </RelativeLayout>


        /***
        Here You can add custom layout
        **/


        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@android:color/white"
            app:tabIndicatorColor="@android:color/holo_blue_light"
            app:tabSelectedTextColor="@color/black"
            app:tabTextColor="@color/black" />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/viewpager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>


</android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>
```